# How can I retain rds endpoint, address, arn while importing rds instance into module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I'm looking to manage an existing RDS instance using a module.

Fetching the data through the module seemed initially fine, but when attempting to maintain the resources, it appeared that the ARN, endpoint, and address were being altered during Terraform planning.

As we're keen to avoid changes to the endpoint from the development side, I attempted to retrieve this information as output variables of the module within the root module's main.tf file. However, this approach seems to be resulting in a circular reference.

Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

```
    .
    ├── main.tf
    └── modules
        └── aws_rds
            ├── rds_instance.tf
            ├── output.tf
            └── variables.tf
```

In the rds_instance.tf file, I inserted:

```
data "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  db_instance_identifier = var.identifier
}
```

to retrieve:

```
output "rds_arn" {
  value = data.aws_db_instance.example.arn
}
```

I'm currently trying to proceed with this change to fetch the arn, but encountering a red underline on the arn part.

Comment: Please provide the code you have along with any outputs that might be beneficial to identifying the potential issues.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`db_instance_arn`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/db_instance#db_instance_arn), i.e:

```
output "rds_arn" {
  value = data.aws_db_instance.example.db_instance_arn
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Marko. I've attempted the suggested solution, but I encountered the following error:

│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with module.rds_instance.aws_db_instance.default,
│   on ../modules/rds/aws_db_instance.tf line 2, in resource "aws_db_instance" "default":
│    2:   arn                    = var.arn
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "arn": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.
╵
This issue persists for attributes like address and endpoint as well.

Comment: The person I talked to yesterday told me that even if I call it using this, if there is an update, the one I called may differ from the one in the code, violating idempotency. Could this be a misuse in the initial design?

Comment: Well, the error you posted is a completely different one compared to the original question. You cannot set an ARN for any resource in AWS, because that's something that the attribute any given resource gets **after** it has been created. There is really too little details to know what you want to achieve. And it warrants a different question.